# Alternative to using a ternary operator in Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, resharper, ternary-operator

Currently.. my code looks like this.

```
PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault() != null ? x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber : string.Empty,
```

PhoneNumbers is an `ICollection<PhoneNumber>`

This is also in a `.Select()`, so I can't really create a variable for it outside.

Resharper is complaining that `x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault()` could be null, and to be honest, not sold on the idea that I gotta do a FirstOrDefault twice.

Any other ideas, I'm thinking there could be another Lambda method I can do something similar.

Comment: Well, the biggest problem with that code is that you're iterating your sequence twice.  If it's representing a database query (which seems to be the case) that's...very bad.

Comment: I agree, definitely not the best idea, as it is the results from the database that I am manipulating into a model

Comment: Since this is coming from a DB, it might be better to simply use a stored proceedure and map the results to a complex type. I've done this in cases where the joining and aggregation of data for reporting/display purposes got quite involved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumbers.Select(pn => pn.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault() ?? "",
```

Answer (score 8):

First option, like Markus's:

```
PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumbers.Select(x => x.PhoneNumber)
                            .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

Another alternative:

```
PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumbers.Select(x => x.PhoneNumber)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty("")
                            .First();
```

Or if you find yourself doing this a lot, you could write your own method to combine the two:

```
public static TElement ProjectedFirstOrDefault<TSource, TElement>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TElement> selector,
     TElement defaultValue) where TElement : class
{
    var firstElement = source.FirstOrDefault();
    return firstElement == null ? defaultValue : selector(firstElement);
}
```

Then:

```
PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumbers.ProjectedFirstOrDefault(x => x.PhoneNumber, "");
```

Comment: @Servy: Well it was either a matter of providing alternatives or just deleting my answer. (In fact I did delete my answer until I thought of the alternatives.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new List<Product>();

result = result.Where(o => o.Name == (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_nameParameter) ? o.Name : _nameParameter)).ToList();
```